# Search Elements in div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a search bar for a `div` that contains several images. I have the search working, but when it hides the elements that don't fit the search, there are just spaces between the elements. What I want to happen is to have the remaining elements reposition themselves next to each other. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JnBmL/14/) to show what I have so far. Try entering "a" or "b" into the search field and you'll see what I mean.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden`.

---

- `display: none` removes the element from the DOM. Example:

  ```
  .cheshire_cat {
      display: none;
  }
  ```

  The element will be completely gone, like if it wasn't there.
- `visibility: hidden` acts like the element is completely transparent. Example:

  ```
  .ninja {
      color: black;
      visibility: hidden;
  }
  ```

  The element will still be there, at the same position, occupying the same space, but you just won't be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
objects[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

to this

```
objects[i].style.display = 'none';
```

and to show the images again

```
objects[i].style.display = '';
```